# Three.js - time the moment the objects appear on the screen

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, gpu, onload-event

Is there a way to time when my objects actually appear onto the screen?

Like a `onLoad` event for the graphics processing unit (GPU).

I want to time performance difference of my different implementations to make a validated choice between different solutions I have for handling my geometries.

Mostly to see the difference between differently built buffer geometries (indexed, non-indexed, native buffer geometries, or buffer geometries that were converted from other geometries).

### EDIT:

I tried to use `console.time('loading')` and `console.timeEnd('loading')`, but I don't seem to manage to put them where they fire at the right moment. `timeEnd` seems to fire when parsing is done and that is way before the objects actually appear on the screen. 
 I guess just need to know where to place these methods.

Comment: could try using console.time()  and timeEnd()

Comment: @maioman Yes I tried that, but doesn't work... At least not where I put them. I updated my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before adding the object in question to the scene, record the average time it takes to render a blank scene by timing the call to `renderer.render( scene, camera );`
Then, add the object in question with `scene.add();`, and record how long `renderer.render( scene, camera );` takes now. Subtract the difference.